# Is there an Erlang function to get the Erlang system (erl.exe or werl.exe) OS PID?

Tags: operating-system, erlang, process

I would like to get the (windows 7) OS PID of the Erlang system (werl.exe) from within my Erlang code. Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
os:getpid().
```

And thats all there is to it. Cheers.